# Python - How to find the redirected URL using Requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests

url = "https://zephr.app/pu?u=db3f63382398497c8d6a52b06cd7a880"
headers =  {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36"}
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
for res in response.history:
    print(res.url)
```

I find a solution online but this didn't solve my problem.

And the response code I got is 503.
But if I open this link, this will redirect to another link.
Appreciate it if you can help me out!
this is the url
https://zephr.app/pu?u=db3f63382398497c8d6a52b06cd7a880

Answer (score 1):

To get the resultant URL after you've been redirected, you can do `r.url`.

```
r = requests.get('https://zephr.app/pu?u=db3f63382398497c8d6a52b06cd7a880') 
print(r.url) # https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtu.be
```

Comment: Thanks for your answering, but I still got the original URL
https://zephr.app/pu?u=db3f63382398497c8d6a52b06cd7a880